# How to loop through and edit records from database entity table that has a checkbox checked in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm having a hard time getting this to work. I'm new to MVC and web development. I've looked up lots of other examples but none work for me. Most either add new records or the multi-select checkboxes are for singular records. So what I want to accomplish is I have a form that has a list of all the records from the database table called 'ProductOrders'. I have a checkbox on each row for each individual product. I'd like to be able to go down the list and check whatever checkboxes I want whether it be one or many. Then when I'm done checking the checkboxes I need, when I hit submit it loops through the records and edits/updates the values of several of the columns from the table. For example, if I have 5 products from an order and I checked #1, #3, and #4, when submitted it would edit the values I specify from only those rows (1,3,& 4). I need to figure out how to get the "ProductOrderID" value of each row that's checked so it doesn't edit/update older posts in the table that have a checked checkbox value, it needs to be specific to that row where the checkbox is checked. Here's what I got so far, but it keeps telling me I don't have an object reference for the "foreach" part in the view.

View:

```
   @model IEnumerable<AMS_ITAMSdb.Models.ProductOrder>
   @using AMS_ITAMSdb.Models
   @using AMS_ITAMSdb.Controllers

   @{
      ViewBag.Title = "ReturnOrder";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
       <div class="title">
           <h4>Return Order</h4>
       </div>
       <p class="filter-section">
           <label class="filter-lbl1">Order #:&nbsp;</label>@Html.TextBox("orderNum", "", new { @class = "num" })<label class="lbl-txt">&nbsp;<i>(Type in order number here)</i></label>
           <input type="submit" value="Search" />&nbsp;
           <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ReturnOrder")'">Reset</button>
       </p>
   }
   <table class="table">
       <tr>
           <th>
               Order #
           </th>
           <th>
               Product Code
           </th>
           <th>
               Qty Ordered
           </th>
           <th>
               Qty Available
           </th>
           <th>
               Return?
           </th>
           <th>
               New Qty Available
           </th>
       </tr>

       @foreach(var item in Model)
       {
           using(Html.BeginForm())
           { 
               <tr>
                 <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelitem => item.ProductOrderID)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.OrderID)
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Product_Code)
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Qty_Ordered)
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Qty_Available)
                 </td>
                 <td class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="@item.Returned" name="checkRec" value="true" />
                 </td>
                 <td>
                 </td>
               </tr>
           }
       }
   </table><br /><br />
              <div class="tbl-footer">
                 @using(Html.BeginForm("ReturnedOrder", "ProductOrders", FormMethod.Post))
                  {
                      <input type="submit" class="button" />
                  }
              </div><br /><br />
```

and my controller is:

```
       //GET: ProductOrders/ReturnOrder
       public ActionResult ReturnOrder(string orderNum, ProductOrder productOrder)
       {
           if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(orderNum))
           {
               //Filter results based on OrderID entered in textbox
               var prod = db.ProductOrders.Where(x => x.OrderID.ToString() == orderNum);
               return View(prod.ToList());
           }
           else
           {
               var product = db.ProductOrders.OrderBy(x => x.OrderID).Where(x => x.Returned == null);
               return View(product.ToList());
           }
       }

       //POST: ProductOrders/ReturnedOrder/
       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult ReturnedOrder(ProductOrder productOrder, bool checkRec = false)
       {
            if (checkRec == true)
            {
                productOrder.Qty_Returned = productOrder.Qty_Returned;
                productOrder.Qty_Available = productOrder.Qty_Ordered + productOrder.Qty_Available;
                productOrder.Qty_On_Hand = productOrder.Qty_On_Hand - productOrder.Qty_Ordered;
                db.Entry(productOrder).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

                Product product = db.Products.Where(x => x.ProductID == productOrder.ProductID).FirstOrDefault();
                product.Qty_Available = productOrder.Qty_Available;
                db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            };                                            
            return View("ReturnOrder");
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for quite some time and don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain your controller is passing records to your view? Try placing a break point at both returns from your controller and inspect your prod object.

Comment: yes, it is passing the records to the view. It lists them all perfectly. I have a textbox in the header to filter the records by order #. That all works fine. But it will not get the values from the checkboxes when I submit the form.

Comment: It's not passed as a property in the productOrder object like productOrder.returned?

Comment: Also It looks like your submit button is in a form all by itself and your rows are in a separate form without submit buttons. Just curious if the submit button current passes any information?

Comment: yeah I'm not sure if I have that right on the submit button. I didn't want to put it in the table and have a separate submit button for each record. I want to go down the list and check however many checkboxes and have the submit button update it all at once. But like I said, I'm new to MVC so it very well could have structured wrong there. To answer your question though, no it doesn't pass any information, it just keeps giving me different error messages like "object not set to reference", "null values not allowed" etc.

Comment: I've also tried it with the productOrder.Returned too and it did the same thing. The "checkRec" was the newest attempt at trying something different lol.

Comment: First issue, you need to have a submit button within the form or it won't bind to the objects and send them back to your controller method. Second issue is you might have problems retaining selections made if your table has a page 2 3 4 etc.. I'd move the submit into the rows for now to try and get that working first.

Comment: This page is meant for returning products back to stock. So although I will probably have to eventually add a page index, it will pretty much just be filtered to show a particular order # and the products associated with it. So theoretically once it’s filtered it should all be on one page when I check the checkboxes. I’ll try putting the submit button in the form and see if that works. I’d really like to have just one button though to edit those records instead of line by line.

Comment: You can also link the checkbox check/uncheck to a javascript function which makes an ajax call to update the individual record without reloading the entire page.

Comment: So I put the submit button within the form of the table and I keep getting an error message of "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on the `foreach(var item in Model)`. However, when I check my database table, it made the edited changes. So I'm not sure how the object is not set to a reference if its finding the record and editing it in the database?

Comment: Add a break point on your view at the foreach statement and examine the Model. Make sure it's receiving a collection to loop through.

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used a breakpoint before as I'm still so new this. I know how to place the breakpoint but how do I see if it's receiving a collection to loop through?

Comment: Ok so upon debugging I figured out what was giving me that error. I feel really dumb now lol. It was in my controller I had to add `var product = db.ProductOrders.OrderBy(x => x.OrderID).Where(x => x.Returned == false);
return View(product.ToList());` and that fixed it. The `foreach` loop was going off of the GET part and wasn't set to that in the POST part. So it's working correctly now! I just need to hopefully figure out if its possible to move the submit button off the table row. Thank you so much for the help @Ramp2010!!!

Comment: Once you hit the break point and your code is paused, you can hover over the element to see it's properties if it has any.

Comment: So you don't really need to use a submit button you can instead use the checkbox on click action to trigger a javascript function that makes an Ajax call to your controller method to update this single record with the new checkbox status.

Comment: AHA! I didn't know that you could check the breakpoint properties that easily. I thought you had to add it and then specify a setting or something. I will definitely remember that for future reference. In regards to the AJAX function, I like the sound of that, but I have little to no knowledge of the in's and outs of writing a function in it. I will definitely do some research and look into doing that! Thanks again!

Comment: If you can mark my response as the accepted answer that would be great.